# How can I get Emacs to run correctly in a Windows console with codepage 65001 (UTF-8)?

Tags: windows, emacs, powershell, console, code-page

When my codepage is set to 65001 (UTF-8) in a Powershell terminal, `emacs -nw` displays garbage. When the codepage is set to 437, `emacs -nw` works.

I would like to be able to run `emacs -nw` (much quicker startup that way) and still have the codepage set to 65001 (UTF-8).

Comment: Are you sure you need the UTF-8? many complain that UTF-8 support is broken in Windows console. You might try to use other codepage that fits your needs. Take a look at the MSDN codepage Identifiers: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317756(v=vs.85).aspx to locate one that might fit your needs.

Comment: @manuelvigarcia In general, yes.  But I don’t use windows anymore, and I don’t think the problem is solvable in general, since Windows stdio is borked when it comes to non-ASCII data.